# AngularJS Typeahead and $http request limiting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm trying to limit the amount of results Angular Bootstrap Typeahead returns when doing Async calls but it's not working at all.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" 
placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue) | limitTo:3" 
typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
```

I added `limitTo:3` to test it out in the Plunker example but it doesn't work, is there a way to do this or is this a bug in Typeahead?

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2vb6YYeBxm1UlM8ZXVvv?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think typeahead filters aren't working with async calls.
See this thread : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/993

It may be not as elegant, but you can filter results in the fetching function.